# Radio button unchecks itself after radiobutton.setChecked(false)

Tags: android

In my activity `onCreate` I set a `onCheckedChangeListener` to a radio group.
At some point I need to programmatically uncheck any checked radio button within the radio group so I unset the listener, uncheck the button, and set the listener back to prevent it from firing when programmatically unchecking the button.

When first checking the radio button, it takes a photo trough an intent. In the `onActivityResult` part, I uncheck the button if the user didn't take a photo. After doing this, the radio button unchecks itself whenever it's checked. How can I fix this problem?

This is my code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_checklist_vestuarios);

    instanciar_objetos();
    instanciar_listeners();
}

private void instanciar_objetos(){
    ctx = getApplicationContext();
    rg_1 = findViewById(R.id.radio_1_1);
}

private void instanciar_listeners(){
    listener_radio_groups = new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            last_rg = radioGroup;
            seleccionar_radio((RadioButton) findViewById(last_rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
        }
    };

    rg_1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener_radio_groups);
}

private void seleccionar_radio(RadioButton rb){
    String tag = (String) rb.getTag();
    String[] s = tag.split("_");
    seccion = s[0];
    item = s[1];
    radio = s[2];
    if(radio.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
        //MARCÓ SI, MANDARLE CON LA FOTO
        fotografia();
    }
    else{
        //MARCO OTRA OPCION, PEDIR TEXTO
    }
}

public void fotografia(){
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            return;
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            try{

                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ctx,
                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = timeStamp;
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/hrtech/hites/originales";
    File storageDir = new File(root, "/"+seccion+"/"+item);
    storageDir.mkdirs();
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Show the thumbnail on ImageView
        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        final File file = new File(imageUri.getPath());

        // ScanFile so it will be appeared on Gallery
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(ctx,
                new String[]{imageUri.getPath()}, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    }
                });
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(ctx,"Obligatoriamente debe tomar una foto para marcar \"SI\" en este ítem.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        last_rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        RadioButton aux = (RadioButton) findViewById(last_rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        aux.toggle();
        last_rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener_radio_groups);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your intention? radiobutton.setChecked(false); will uncheck the RadioButton.

Comment: I tried using setChecked(false) and it unchecks the radio as expected, but after doing that, whenever i check the radio again it instantly unchecks itself.

Comment: Show your `seleccionar_radio`

Comment: I eddited my post and added my full code. The seleccionar_radio is non relevant, it's just a function that does something base on the tag of the selected radio